# How to convert LinkedBlockingQueue<Tweet> in ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, database, inputstream, objectinputstream

I'm working on a tool that analyze a stream of tweets. Actually I have this situation:

```
String filename = config.getFile();
fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

The stream of tweets is taken from a file. I need to do it from a database

```
private void readfromDB() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs;
    String query = "SELECT* FROM myselection";
    rs = dbConn.retrieveData(query);

    while(rs.next()) {
        Long id = rs.getLong(1);
        String text = rs.getString(2);
        Instant ts = rs.getTimestamp(3).toInstant();
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet(id, text, ts);
        buffer.add(tweet);

    }

}
```

Is it possible to convert a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Tweet>` buffer in `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: If `Tweet` is `Serializable`, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: yes Tweet is Serializable. Can you explain how i have to do?

Comment: Nobody can help me?! Please